# Python requests url link which contains a variable part

Tags: python, csv, url, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to request a list of urls which have the following formats for example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python/001/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python/002/

....

These codes 001,... I saved in a csv file.

```
import csv
import requests

inputfile = open('trycode.csv','r')
for row in inputfile:
    url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python/'
    source = requests.get(url + row/)
```

And obviously it doesn't work... How can I correctly call these urls with the last part coming from the csv file?

Many thanks!

Comment: Apart from the extra '/' at the end, which is a syntax error, why does this "obviously" not work?

Comment: Your code throw exceptions or it works incorrect?

Comment: Maybe you mean `url + row + '/'` ?  Or `'%s%s/' % (url, row)`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The problem is the url in the end contains a / , so I don't know how to put it. without the / , the url add is not correct.

Comment: @larsks yes, you are right, I tried to put instead now url + row +'/', but when I print the url link, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python/00%A2/, not http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python/002/,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually using a Comma Separated Value format for your file? Seems if just a short string, I'd use a txt file, but that's just me.

It's always a good idea to build your string URL before trying to call it... this way you can inspect it first... also important to close your file:

```
import csv
import requests

inputfile = open('trycode.csv','r')
for row in inputfile:
    url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python/' + row
    source = requests.get(url)
inputfile .close()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! But when I tried your code, for example using a row entry "01020" I always get https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python/01020%0A, ideally I want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python/010200, maybe something wrong with my file format?

Comment: Looks like &0A is a URL-encoded newline character... check your source file to ensure that you have clean data, or Replace the %0A before using the value from each line.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at the file to see if its a clean txt file.